# How to use the Gmulti package with a multinomial logistic regression in r

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I need to do a multinomial logistic regression with a nominal variable, and I've heard about the Gmulti package in r ,and how it provides automatic selection methods models, However all the examples that i found are only applied on binaire logistic regression, so I wonder if it's even working on a multinomial logistic regression and in case is true, is the Gmulti take in consideration the problem of multicolinearity between the independents variables. Please help me thank you